# ESRI ArcMap ArcObjects C#: Project geometry with user defined transformation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, c#

I have routines which project geometries from the `projectedCS DHDN_GK_3` to `projectedCS ETRS89_32N` using the available predefined ESRI Transformation `esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_DHDN_To_ETRS_1989_8_NTv2` and this works well:

```
private void ProjectPoint(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point pt)
{
    ISpatialReference pSourceCoordSystem;
    ISpatialReference pTargetCoordSystem;
    IGeoTransformation pGeoTrans;
    ISpatialReferenceFactory pSpatRefFact;

    pSpatRefFact = new SpatialReferenceEnvironment();
    // Create the source coordinate system.
    pSourceCoordSystem = pSpatRefFact.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem( (int)esriSRProjCS4Type.esriSRProjCS_DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_3);
    // Create the output coordinate system.
    pTargetCoordSystem = pSpatRefFact.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem( (int)esriSRProjCS4Type.esriSRProjCS_ETRS1989_UTM_Zone_32N);

    // Create a geographic transformation between the input and output 
    // geographic coordinate systems are different.
    pGeoTrans = (IGeoTransformation)pSpatRefFact.CreateGeoTransformation((int) esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_DHDN_To_ETRS_1989_8_NTv2 );

    // Create a geometry object and project it. 
    pt.SpatialReference = pSourceCoordSystem;
    IGeometry2 pGeometry = (IGeometry2)pt;
    pGeometry.ProjectEx( pTargetCoordSystem, esriTransformDirection.esriTransformForward, pGeoTrans, false, 0.0, 0.0);

    MessageBox.Show( pt.X.ToString() + " / " + pt.Y.ToString());

}
```

Now I would like to use my own user-defined transformation method which I created and saved in ArcMap. So I would have to replace the line

```
pGeoTrans = (IGeoTransformation)pSpatRefFact.CreateGeoTransformation((int)
esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_DHDN_To_ETRS_1989_8_NTv2 );
```

with something like

```
pGeoTrans = (IGeoTransformation)pSpatRefFact.**Load**GeoTransformation((int)
esriSRGeoTransformationType.esriSRGeoTransformation_DHDN_To_ETRS_1989_8_NTv2 );
```

This `Load` function is nonexisting. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I found it out myself:

The function ISpatialReferenceFactory2.GetPredefinedGeographicTransformations() returns not only the ESRI predefined transformations but adds all user defined transformations of the specific ESRI ArcGIS instance. So I wrote the following function:

```
    private IGeoTransformation FindGeoTransformation(string sName)
    {
        ISpatialReferenceFactory2 pSpatRefFact2 = (ISpatialReferenceFactory2)new SpatialReferenceEnvironment();

        ISet transSet = pSpatRefFact2.GetPredefinedGeographicTransformations();
        IGeoTransformation trans;

        for (int i = 0; i < transSet.Count; i++)
        {
            trans = (IGeoTransformation)transSet.Next();
            if (trans.Name.Contains( sName))
                return trans;

        }

        return null;
    }
```